# Tcl String Manipulation and Substitution

Tags: string, tcl, substitution

```
set i 0
set student$i tom
```

(of course, this is equivalent to `set student0 tom`)

I want to get the value of `student0`, that is, string "tom". How can I get it if I have to use `$i` to represent `0` here? I tried `$(student$i)` or `$"student$i"` and many other ways, but I cannot get string "tom". (I don't want to hard code it like `$student0`) in here.

Is there any way to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: You may be able to use `eval` in some way.

Comment: @jeffamaphone: no, `eval` isn't necessary. It will do nothing but make the problem even more complicated.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `set` command -- it returns the value of the variable:

```
puts "the student is [set student$i]"
```

However, this sort of thing is generally more trouble than it's worth. Use an array, with `i` as an index into the array:

```
set student($i) tom
puts "the student is $student($i)"
```

Comment: If the indexes are integers, a `list` may be better than an array.

Comment: @potrzebie It might be more efficient, but arrays are pretty convenient when you want to throw some code together…

Answer (score 1):

1] set i 0

set student$i "tom"

puts [subst $[subst student[subst $i]]]

2] Using Array

set i 0

set student($i) "tom"

puts $student($i)